Why doesn't Saito recognise Cobb in the beginning?
I wanna know, as the question says, why Saito doesn't recognise Cobb in the beginning. Is it his limbo self's old-age memory issues? Something else?
Does he remember Cobb's face at all? If not, does he recognise him after discovering he's Cobb just after hearing “filled with regret” from him, or is it just those words, and not Cobb's face, that convince him the guy he's talking to is Cobb?

I havent seen this for years but, iirc:

I wanna know, as the question says, why Saito doesn't recognise Cobb in the beginning.

Because he is very old, its age-related memory issues, and he's been living a very long life that has not seen nor heard of Cobb in all that time, its been so long that he thinks it may have just been a memory of a dream after all...

Is it his limbo self's old-age memory issues? Something else?

Yes, because he aged and is super old - he went into limbo before Cobb did.

Does he remember Cobb's face at all?

He does in the second part of that, which comes at the end.
Besides, Cobb is also a little beardy at this point
278
 EXT. DAWN.  CRASHING SURF.
 The waves TOSS a BEARDED MAN onto wet sand.
 CUT TO:
 As the Japanese Security Guard turns him onto his back, we
 realize that this is Cobb- OLDER.  WEARY.  TRAVELED...


If not, does he recognise him after discovering he's Cobb just after hearing “filled with regret” from him, or is it just those words, and not Cobb's face, that convince him the guy he's talking to is Cobb?

Actually its the totem that kicks in his memories. ("I remember this..")
Up until then its a 'half remembered dream..' The words help, but its seeing the totem, and seeing it spin endlessly, that helps him remember.
Beginning:
The Elderly Japanese Man picks up the cone between thumb and
 forefinger.
 ELDERLY JAPANESE MAN (CONT'D)
 I know what this is.
 He SPINS it onto the table- it CIRCLES gracefully across the
 polished ebony... a SPINNING TOP.
 ELDERLY MAN
 I've seen one before.  Many, many
 years ago...
 The Elderly Japanese Man STARES at the top, mesmerized.
 ELDERLY MAN (CONT'D)
 A man I met in a half-remembered
 dream...
 MOVE IN on the GRACEFULLY SPINNING TOP...
 ELDERLY MAN (CONT'D)
 A man possessed of some radical
 notions...
 The Elderly Japanese Man STARES, remembering...

Ending:
 Cobb does not look up.
 SAITO (CONT'D)
 I've been waiting for someone to
 come for me...
 COBB
 Someone from your half-remembered
 dream..? 
Saito peers at Cobb.
 SAITO
 Cobb?  Not possible- he and I were
 young men together.  And I am an old
 man...

